# Can't malloc when creating structure AVL tree

Tags: c, malloc, memory-address, avl-tree

I am creating an AVL tree in C. The whole code works for a certain amount of inputs (strings in this case) but when I tried to run the program giving, as an argument, a "dictionary" with 10 thousand words at a certain point the program crashes and gives this error:

```
    malloc.c:2392: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && 
    old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse
    (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

And I saw that, when I got to a certain word, when I tried to malloc my structure the program crashed. Here's the code:

```
struct AVLNode
{
   char *words_dic_tree;   
   struct AVLNode* left;   
   struct AVLNode* right; 
   long int height;
};
```

(...)
(main)

```
while (fscanf(dic, "%s", aux_array_dic) == 1)
{
   if (strcmp(aux_array_dic,"revelar")==0)
   distance = 69;
   word_size = strlen(aux_array_dic)+1;
   words_dic = (char*)malloc(word_size * sizeof(char));
   strncpy(words_dic,aux_array_dic,word_size);
   head_AVL = Insert(head_AVL,words_dic);
```

}

(...)

```
struct AVLNode* Insert(struct AVLNode* node, char *words_dic_tree)
{
if (node == NULL){
   return GetNewNode(words_dic_tree);
}
if(strcmp(words_dic_tree,node->words_dic_tree)<0){
   node->left = Insert(node->left, words_dic_tree);
}
else 
   node->right = Insert(node->right,words_dic_tree);

node->height = 1+max(height(node->left),height(node->right));

long int balance = getBalance(node);

if (balance > 1 && strcmp(words_dic_tree,node->left->words_dic_tree) < 0)
   return rightRotate(node);
if (balance < -1 && strcmp(words_dic_tree,node->right->words_dic_tree) > 0)
   return leftRotate(node);
if (balance > 1 && strcmp(words_dic_tree,node->left->words_dic_tree) > 0)
{
   node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
   return rightRotate(node);
}
if (balance < -1 && strcmp(words_dic_tree,node->right->words_dic_tree) < 0)
{
   node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
   return leftRotate(node);
}
return node;
}

struct AVLNode* GetNewNode(char *word)
{
   struct AVLNode* newNode = (struct AVLNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLNode));
   newNode->words_dic_tree = (char *)malloc(sizeof(word));
   strcpy(newNode->words_dic_tree,word);
   newNode->left = NULL;
   newNode->right = NULL;
   newNode->height = 1;
   return newNode;
}
```

I can't understand what's wrong with my code that makes it crash passing a certain amount of words. Is it something related to my computer memory, or something else?

Note: While I was debugging I saw that, when I tried to malloc my structure in the GetNewNode function, the adress of the struct AVL_tree* newnode was "<__GI___libc_malloc+84>". I suspect malloc is out bounds

Comment: `newNode->words_dic_tree = (char *)malloc(sizeof(word));` --> `newNode->words_dic_tree = (char *)malloc(strlen(word)+1);`

Comment: Yeah thanks, now it worked, but I thought making sizeof() returned the whole word + "/0"

Comment: `char *word` is a pointer, and so `sizeof(word)` is the size of a pointer.